# How can I decrease the size of a bitmap without loss of resolution in Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, android-camera

I have an application that takes a picture from the camera and then I do some image processing operations on that picture. But that's taking too long, so I want to decrease the size of the bitmap before the image processing operations. The important part is that resolution must be good in the smaller image also. Is there a library in android or is there anybody who knows an algorithm for that operation?

Comment: Do you want to reduce the size of the entire image, or do you want to want to take a small piece of it and retain it at full size?

Comment: @markransom yes I want to reduce size of the entire image

Comment: Essentially want you want is some form of lossless compression - what file format are the images in? If they're in bitmap then just saving them as a high quality jpeg can reduce the file size a lot. Or you could try run a library like `pngcrush` on them.

Comment: @josephearl file format is jpg but in order to make some image processing operations I changed it to bitmap in android. This bitmap has sizes 1700*1400. as you see It is too big so I want to decrease its size something like 800*600 before image processing operations so what can I do ?

Comment: The easiest way would just be to use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` together with a `BitmapFactory.Options` that had an `inSampleSize` of e.g. 2 - this would result in the image you get being 850*700 (i.e. half the width and height, and a quarter of the memory usage).

Comment: @josephearl thanks it works. I get 160*150 image but how about the resolution. I cant see the new smaller picture so when we get smaller the picture, same time do the resolution becomes low quality or remain same ?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to take the average of every n*n block and convert it to a single pixel. It isn't the absolutely sharpest method and won't be completely free of artifacts, but I think you'll find the real-world results to be acceptable - and it's very fast.

Comment: wont this operation damage shapes of image

Comment: @barzos, the shapes will remain the same but the detail will be reduced.

Comment: @Ashishsingh, sorry I'm not fluent in Android or Java so I'd be likely to mess it up. The concept is simple though if you have pixel-level access to the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
    { Bitmap bit=Shrinkmethod(arrpath1[position], 100, 100); 
       //This reduce the size of image in 1kb size so u can also consider VM nativeheap memory

                    iv.setImageBitmap(bit);//ImageView Obj.

    }


    //To reduce the byte size of image in program

//user defined method to reduce size of image without reducing the quality of img.
        Bitmap Shrinkmethod(String file,int width,int height){
            BitmapFactory.Options bitopt=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitopt.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
            Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bitopt);

            int h=(int) Math.ceil(bitopt.outHeight/(float)height);
            int w=(int) Math.ceil(bitopt.outWidth/(float)width);

            if(h>1 || w>1){
                if(h>w){
                    bitopt.inSampleSize=h;

                }else{
                    bitopt.inSampleSize=w;
                }
            }
            bitopt.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
            bit=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bitopt);



            return bit;

        }

//Try to upload ur project code and idea so that like u and me can get that to develop more android application..

Regard,
pranav
```